# Open Mac Terminal, activate venv and leave the terminal windows running (.command file)

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, python-venv

Using OSX, I want to create an easy shortcut to get a terminal that already has a venv initialized.

I tried creating a .command file with the following:

```
#!/bin/zsh
source /path/to/code/venv-python3.10/bin/activate
cd /path/to/code/my_project_directory/
zsh
```

I double-click the .command file within finder, and my objective is to start up a terminal with the correct venv initialised, so I can continue working in the terminal.

But without the `zsh` at the end, the terminal window auto-exits.
With the `zsh`, it remains open but does not leave me within the virtualenv.

Comment: What command are you using to run the `.command` file you show? (Please paste exactly what you're running in terminal.)

Comment: I'm double-clicking the `.command` file, and my objective is to start up a terminal with the correct venv initialised, so I can continue working in the terminal. But the terminal either exits or I can't start the venv.

Comment: I'm afraid I am not able to reproduce this error; the shell that remains open indicates I am in the `venv`, (the name of the `venv` appears at the start of my prompt.  Are you sure you're not in the `venv`? Perhaps you have customised your shell prompt in such a way it doesn't show that? (I have done this before with `conda`.)

Comment: @baileythegreen are you on zsh or bash?

Comment: My default shell is bash, but I ran the code with `zsh`(and I can tell it's actually being run in `zsh` because it screws up my prompt, and the top of the shell says it's `zsh`).

Comment: I assume you really want this to work from the `.command` file, and that you've already considered alternatives—like defining a function in your `.zshrc` or `.zsh_profile` that runs these lines?

Comment: I don't want all terminal instances to start in that particular venv, just when I'm working on a particular project. My pain point is that I can't remember the source ...activate command and would like to either automate it or make it run via a gui click.

Comment: If you define a command (something short and easy for you to remember, e.g., `start_venv`) that runs those lines in your `.zsh_profile`, that won't automatically cause all instances to start in that virtual environment. It would just make that function available to you. I have some things like this in my `.bash_profile`. This one creates a function, `filecount` that counts the number of non-directory files somewhere: ```function filecount()
{
  echo `ls -p "${@}" | grep -v /$ |wc -l`
}```. But all that happens in the `.bash_profile` is it's defined.